# log normal distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I would like to derive the variance of the following variables:

$Y_1 \sim Z \cdot \exp(W-1)$

$Y_2 \sim Z \cdot \exp(-0.5W-0.25)$

where $W$ and $Z$ are independent $N(0,1)$ variables. From the functional form, I guess that the results of the log-normal distribution can be used. But I don't know how to...

Comment: The variance is derived below, but if you are interested in more general results, this distribution sometimes goes by the name of "normal-lognormal mixture" (or NLN mixture). In the case where $W$ and $Z$ are independent, it is similar to a normal distribution but with fatter tails, a bit like a Student's t distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them have mean zero because $E[Z]=0$ and so the variance of $Y_i$ is $E[Y_i^2]$, $i=1,2$. Now:

$$E[Y_1^2] = E[Z^2]E[\exp(2W-2)]=e^{-2}E[\exp(2W)]$$

because $E[Z^2]$ is the expectation of a $\chi^2(1)$ random variable, which is $1$. Now, $E[e^{2W}]$ is the mgf of a standard normal randdom variable evaluated at $t=2$ which is

$$\left.\exp\left(\frac 1 2 t^2\right)\right|_{t=2}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\times4} = e^2$$

and therefore $\operatorname{Var}(Y_1)=E[Y_1^2] = 1$.

---

Similarly

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y_2)=E[Y_2^2] - 0^2 = \left.1\times e^{\frac 1 2 t^2} \right|_{t=-1} \times e^{-0.5} = 1.$$